# Visual Studio 2017- prevent typescript errors with asmx files

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I installed Visual Studio 2017 community edition. I loaded my project up that has an asmx file. When I compile the project I get a few typescript errors:

```
>    TS1005 ';' expected
>     TS1146 Declaration expected
>     etc.
```

When I double-click on the errors it shows me the asmx file which has one line and looks like this:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="AjaxCalls.asmx.cs" Class="Nova.AjaxCalls" %>
```

Why would typescript give me an error about this line? This is not related to typescript at all. Is Visual Studio showing me the wrong file of where the error is located?

UPDATE :

I found the solution to my problem. I added a reference to my project called Microsoft.CSharp. This fixed the issue. If that reference already exist then try removing it and adding it back. Apparently it has something to do with IntelliSense.

Comment: typescript has nothing to do with this . this is an asmx web service file

Comment: Why is Visual Studio showing me a typescript error for a asmx file?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. It's definitely TypeScript that acts weird on this one (I'm on VS 2017 v.15.4.2). Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Faced the same problem. Do you have solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrading the installed typescript nuget package from 1.8 to 2.4 solved it for me.**

It's important to note that when saving typescript files VS2017 uses the version of typescript installed on the computer (default 2.4 with VS2017)

But your code could be using an older version of typescript when hitting "build". compared to when hitting ctrl+s, or just looking at errors in the IDE.

This is because typescript as a nuget package (v1.8 for example), adds targets that msbuild uses to compile the typescript when building.

But that is not what the VS2017 IDE uses to show error messages, it uses the newest version installed on the pc.

This mismatch between versions could be what is causing issues. showing errors but not failing to ctrl+s compile / msbuild build.

Try installing/uninstalling typescript nuget package and check up on which version is installed locally on the pc and if the project itself has a nuget package with a corresponding version or not.